# Error System.PlatformNotSupportedException : Operation is not supported on this platform

Tags: selenium, browserstack

My intention is to run our UI automation scripts on browser stack
I was trying to run a simple sample test on browser stack -but I am getting below error

> Message: System.PlatformNotSupportedException : Operation is not supported on this platform
>   Full stack trace
>   System.Net.SystemWebProxy.GetProxy(Uri destination) at System.Net.ServicePointManager.ProxyAddressIfNecessary(Uri& address, IWebProxy proxy) at System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Uri address, IWebProxy proxy) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.get_ServicePoint() at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(H‌​ttpRequestInfo requestInfo) –

My code looks like this below:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using NUnit;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
   [TestFixture]
   [Parallelizable]
   public class Program
   {
      IWebDriver _driver;

      [SetUp]
      public void init()
      {
         DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
         capability.SetCapability("browserstack.user", "<BrowserStack-Username>");
         capability.SetCapability("browserstack.key", "<BrowserStack-Key>");
         capability.SetCapability("browser", "Chrome");
         capability.SetCapability("browser_version", "52.0");
         capability.SetCapability("os", "Windows");
         capability.SetCapability("os_version", "7");

         _driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
           new Uri("http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), capability
         );

      }

      [Test]

      public void BSTTest4()
      {
         _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
         Console.WriteLine(_driver.Title);

         IWebElement query = _driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
         query.SendKeys("Browserstack");
         query.Submit();
         Console.WriteLine(_driver.Title);

      }

      [TearDown]
      public void cleanup()
      {
         _driver.Quit();

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: There must be a way to get a more complete backtrace. Assume no one else can run this the way you can. Find out what operation it is complaining about.

Comment: Thank you for responseThank you for response-please find below stack trace                             
   at System.Net.SystemWebProxy.GetProxy(Uri destination)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.ProxyAddressIfNecessary(Uri& address, IWebProxy proxy)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Uri address, IWebProxy proxy)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.get_ServicePoint()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at

Comment: The backtrace should be in the body of the question, properly formatted.